# Where is max and min functions length to validate a string in superstructjs?

Tags: javascript

In `superstructjs` how to check the min and max of string length? can't find it [in the docs](https://docs.superstructjs.org/api-reference/types#string).

Also `superstructjs` provide min and max functions but it's date function.

Is it possible to do with `superstructjs`? or should I write my own custom function?

Comment: _how to check the min and max of string?_ what do you mean by that?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [size()](https://docs.superstructjs.org/api-reference/refinements#size) for that.

```
const sizeStruct = size(string(), 3, 5);

assert('ab', sizeStruct); //Fail: Expected a string with a length between `3` and `5` but received one with a length of `2`

assert('abc', sizeStruct); // success

assert('abcdef', sizeStruct); // Fail: Expected a string with a length between `3` and `5` but received one with a length of `6`
```